# populate mongodb database with json in spring project

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson, spring-data-mongodb

So, i try to populate my mondodb database if it's empty using some json file and jackson.

i have :

```
@Bean
public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean getRespositoryPopulator() {
    Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("aotyType.json")});
    factory.setResources(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("badge.json")});
    return factory;
}
```

The things is that when i populate the database I only have new ObjectId and not the info from the json

BUT

when i just put the json in mongodb using mongodb compass the json work

hope someone can help me...

thanks for reading

Comment: can you please add the domain type and a the json representation used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem initially. My problem was, in JSON file instead of `id`, I used `_id`. Once I change that to `id`, `ObjectId` reflected the one in JSON.

Therefore instead of fields in your MongoDB document, use fields in your spring-data java class.

Here's a example JSON file.

```
{
  "id" : "your_id_field",
  "name" : "jsonMetaSchema",
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "title" : "Core schema meta-schema",
  "_class" : "uk.ac.ebi.jsonschemastore.model.mongo.MongoMetaSchema"
}
```